# Does a windows 8 bootable usb work even after installing kali linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux

I recently installed Kali Linux off a bootable USB drive, and am running Windows 10 as my primary system. For me to be able to boot off an external media I had to disable secure boot and change from UEFI boot to CSM boot in the BIOS menu.

I did that and was able to boot into Kali Linux from a USB drive (did not boot it live, but installed it). My aim was to dual boot the system. It turned out my Windows 10 couldn't appear in the GNU GRUB menu. Now I don't want Kali any more, I want to go back to either Windows 8 or 10.

Do those changes that I've made earlier in the BIOS menu still apply? Will I be able to boot back to Windows from Kali Linux?